# parsing space delimited, named fields

Tags: python, regex, parsing, csv, dictionary

I have a specific format of data (exported from [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)>) which is a mixture of CSV and named fields. I would like to understand if it is possible in Python to parse such data via a template (or a simplified, average-human understandable regex)

```
"Harry Potter", "book", "12 Mar 2014 note=""good"" language=""English"""
"Forrest Gump", "movie", "14 March 2015 note=""good"" language=""Aztec"""
```

As you can see the first fields are comma separated, then comes one long string which starts with a date and then I have a few named fields (`note`, `language`).

I would like to build a list of dicts solely from the named fields:

```
[
    {'note': 'good', 'language'='English'},
    {'note': 'good', 'language'='Aztec'}
]
```

After parsing the CSV I end up with the last field (e.g. `"12 Mar 2014 note=""good"" language=""English"""` for the first line) and then I am stuck, the only solution I can think of is to try to describe the line in regex (which is scary :). Even if I managed to extract the tuples, how to translate them to a dict?

Comment: If the last field is not particularly complex and is pretty much fixed in the format you've specified, then you can go ahead and use regex to get the data.

Comment: Is it possible for the text in the named fields to contain spaces?  E.g. `note=""very good""`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: yes, sorry I should have made it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csv` module will handle the outer *and* doubled quoting for you, out of the box. Your columns have outer quotes (making sure delimiters, quotes and newlines in the values are preserved), and any quotes in the values are doubled; the `csv.reader()` will remove the outer quotes and return strings with single quotes for the 3rd column.

The named fields can be handled by a regular expression:

```
import csv
import re

keyvalue = re.compile(r'([^"= ]+)="([^"]+)"')


with open(filename, 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh, skipinitialspace=True)
    namedfields = [dict(keyvalue.findall(row[2])) for row in reader]
```

The `skipinitialspace` option removes any spaces after the delimiter; this is needed to ensure that the spaces before the quoted column values are removed correctly, in turn ensuring that the quoting is handled.

The `re.findall()` method here returns a list of `(key, value)` tuples, and the `dict()` type will turn those directly into a dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import re
>>> keyvalue = re.compile(r'([^"= ]+)="([^"]+)"')
>>> sample = '''\
... "Harry Potter", "book", "12 Mar 2014 note=""good"" language=""English"""
... "Forrest Gump", "movie", "14 March 2015 note=""good"" language=""Aztec"""
... '''
>>> reader = csv.reader(sample.splitlines(True), skipinitialspace=True)
>>> [dict(keyvalue.findall(row[2])) for row in reader]
[{'note': 'good', 'language': 'English'}, {'note': 'good', 'language': 'Aztec'}]
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot. I really need to study comprehensions as they seem to be some kind of voodoo which then turns into a Graal.

Comment: @WoJ: The list comprehension is just a shortcut to building a list from a loop. `namedfields = []`, then `for row in reader: namedfields.append(dict(keyvalue.findall(row[2])))` would be the explicit-loop alternative.